# python gaana.com api python hmac encoding

Tags: python, api, base64, hmac

So I have been stuck here since a week now.searched every thing.tried many thing.

This is regarding gaana.com API / [user registration :](http://developer.gaana.com/resources/user-data-api/login-management/.)

I need to *encode a key* - this is the definition given on the site -
to encode a reg token do this -

```
hash_hmac(‘md5′,base_64_encode(‘regtoken from User Registration Token)’),md5(‘Private Key Provided’))
```

I am getting this error -

{'Status': 0, 'user-token-status': 1, 'user_token_status': 1, 'Error': 'Regtoken expire or missing'}

Things I have tried -

1) `hmac.new(base64.b64encode(gaana_obj.getUserToken()['regtoken']),'',md5).hexdigest()`

2)  `hmac.new(base64.b64encode(gaana_obj.getUserToken()['regtoken']),'',md5).hexdigest()`

3) even tried replacing `hexdigest()` to `digest()`..

I hope someone can help..
Thanks in advance